# I can't get my error message box to work in pyqt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

In my init function, i've defined an error message box like this:

```
 self.error_msg = QtGui.QMessageBox()
 self.error_msg.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.critical)
 self.error_msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
 self.error_msg.setDetailedText("")
```

on a different method, I try to call the message box like this, by setting the error text:

```
def detectRoot(self):
    euid = os.geteuid()
    if euid != 0:
        print "need to be root to run this program"
        self.logger.error("Not root, program exited")
        self.error_msg.setText("You need to be root to run this program")
        self.error_msg.exec_()
        exit(1)
```

However, I keep getting message a pyqt/python error:

```
self.error_msg.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.critical)
TypeError: QMessageBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon): argument 1 has unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: I got the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#Icon-enum):

> **QMessageBox::NoIcon**: The message box does not have any icon.
>
> **QMessageBox::Question**: An icon indicating that the message is asking a question.
> **QMessageBox::Information**: An icon indicating that the message is nothing out of the ordinary.
> **QMessageBox::Warning**: An icon indicating that the message is a warning, but can be dealt with.
>
> **QMessageBox::Critical**: An icon indicating that the message represents a critical problem.

Change `QtGui.QMessageBox.critical` to `QtGui.QMessageBox.Critical`

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc